# Determine if tmux has a detached session

Tags: scripting, tmux

I'd love to be able to write a script that checked for the presence of a `tmux` session and attach it, or if no session exists, start a new one.  So that I could create a custom command in my `.zshrc` file, and not have to always check.

Is there a way to check programmatically that I have a `tmux` screen session running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer over on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432536/tmux-create-session-if-none-exists

```
tmux attach || tmux new
```

Answer (score 1):

`tmux ls` will list running sessions

If you're using this inside a .shrc file or similar with `exec` I'd recommend

```
if tmux ls
  exec tmux attach
else
  exec tmux
fi
```